# UICollectionView move cells reverts after clicking a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collectionview with interactive cells, I am using a long press gesture recognizer on the cells to allow the user to re-arrange them.

Now the re-arrange itself is working perfectly the issue I have is once the cells have been re-arranged if I click on one of the cells they revert back to the positions they were in before the re-arrange occured.

I have a feeling this has something to do with the datasource but im not sure.

This is the long press gesture that re-arranges the cells.

```
-(IBAction)longPressGestureRecognized:(id)sender {

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender;
UIGestureRecognizerState state = longPress.state;

CGPoint location = [longPress locationInView:self.collectionView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:location];

static UIView *snapshot = nil;
static NSIndexPath *sourceIndexPath = nil;

switch (state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
        if (indexPath) {
            sourceIndexPath = indexPath;

            UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            snapshot = [self customSnapshotFromView:cell];

            CGPoint center = cell.center;
            snapshot.center = center;
            snapshot.alpha = 0.0;
            [self.collectionView addSubview:snapshot];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{


                snapshot.center = center;
                snapshot.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05);
                snapshot.alpha = 0.98;

                cell.hidden = YES;
            } completion:nil];
        }
        break;
    }
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
        CGPoint center = snapshot.center;
        center.y = location.y;
        snapshot.center = center;

        if (indexPath && ![indexPath isEqual:sourceIndexPath]) {
            [people2 exchangeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
            [self.collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:indexPath];
            sourceIndexPath = indexPath;
        }
        break;
    }
    default: {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

            snapshot.center = cell.center;
            snapshot.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            snapshot.alpha = 0.0;
            cell.hidden = NO;

        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [snapshot removeFromSuperview];
            snapshot = nil;



        }];
        sourceIndexPath = nil;
        break;
    }
}
```

}

I am using NSNotification to reload the cells on a click event.

```
-(void)handleReload:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"Notification Recieved");
people2 = [databaseClass getData];
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

}

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

EDIT:
The [databaseclass getData] method -

```
+(NSMutableArray*)getData {
[self databaseInit];

peopleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &peopleDB)== SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *selectSQL = @"SELECT ID, NAME, POINTS, COLOUR FROM PEOPLE";
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(peopleDB,[selectSQL UTF8String],-1,&statement,NULL);

        while (sqlite3_step(statement)== SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            PersonObject *newPerson = [[PersonObject alloc]init];
            newPerson.ID = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]integerValue];
            newPerson.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            newPerson.points = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)] integerValue];
            newPerson.colour = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
            [peopleArray addObject:newPerson];

        }

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(peopleDB);

return peopleArray;
```

}

Comment: can you provide me the code for this.I am facing similar problem.I don't understand what is snapshot & people2 from your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how you are getting your data, but this `[databaseClass getData];` suggests it is from some database table.  If you are re-reading the database into the `people2` array then the order of the data in the array will revert to the order returned by your database query.

Comment: You haven't included any "order by" statement in your select and your rearrangement of the data doesn't modify the database in any way, so when you reload the data into your array, the order will revert to that in the database as you are seeing. What is the purpose of re-arranging the data?  What should it change in the underlying database?

Comment: Thanks for this, took what you said and figured it out... really appreciate